# How can i solve a javascript error "undefined" is not a object when using google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

So, i am playing with javafx and google maps and using the javascript api so i came around the following problem.

To clarify i am using the following script source:

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
```

I have the javascript function:

```
document.goToLocation = function goToLocation(x, y) {

var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
    var eastPoint = new google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(latLng, 2000, 90));
    marker.setPosition(latLng);
    map.setCenter(latLng);
}
```

Inside my class i have the following lines of code:

```
webEngine.executeScript("" +
    "window.lat = " + lat + ";" +
    "window.lon = " + lon + ";" +
    "document.goToLocation(window.lat, window.lon);"
};
```

The problem come from the line:

```
 var eastPoint = new google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(latLng, 2000, 90));
```

When i comment this line my program works great and the map appears.

When i don't comment this line i get the following error:

```
netscape.javascript.JSException: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object
at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.twkExecuteScript(Native Method)
at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.executeScript(WebPage.java:1438)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.executeScript(WebEngine.java:811)
at utils.gmaps.WebMap$MyBrowser$2.handle(MyClass.java:77)
```

where line 77 is the line for the execute script function.

What is going on and how can i fix it?

Please help
Ciprian

Comment: Well, clearly one of the components of that compound property accessor yields `undefined` and you're trying to dereference that as though it were an object. So use the debugger built into your browser, stop on that line, and look at the object structure to find out which part it is. E.g., is `google.maps` an object? If so, is `google.maps.geometry` an object? If so, is `google.maps.geometry.spherical` an object?

Comment: You have an extra `)` in `var eastPoint = new google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(latLng, 2000, 90));`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry, that was a typo, i solved it and the problem still reproduces.

Comment: You forgot to load the geometry-library(it's not loaded by default with the maps-API). https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries

Comment: @Dr.Molle I did according to the link and changes the source to:
'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&sensor=false' and it still did not work

Comment: did not work.... that's really a useful info

Comment: @Dr.Molle sorry for being unspecific, what i mean to say is that i have the exact same error that i described in the question details. Now i do realise that the problem is because i did not load the libraries but i can't figure out how to load them, given that the adding the src does not work.

Comment: I doubt that using https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&sensor=false did not load the geometry-library

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/gy2Pu/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was indeed my fault because i did load the correct library. After i managed to get the code right the application worked.

Thank you